# Не всегда получается загрузить данные из Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Мне нужно загрузить текст и фото из firebase и показать из в recycler View. Но почему-то текстовые данные не всегда получается загрузить из сервера и recycler View остается полностью пустой при запуске приложения заново (1 раз загружаются, во 2 раз не загружаются, 3 раз загружаются, а в 4 раз нет и тд). В конце метода, я проверяю пустой ли лист с данными, если да, то возвращаю его в начало это строка `if (childItemList.size() ==0) getChildItemList(category);` Но в таком случае, приложение выдает ошибку в logcat

Фото вообще не получается загрузить. Не важно получаю я ссылку на фото из сервера -  `childItem.setImage(document.getString("image"));` или вставляю в recycler View  готовую ссылку. Дело не в imageView, сам он работает нормально когда я ставлю в него локальное фото, находящееся в самом эмуляторе.

Получаю данные из сервера:

```
     private List<ChildItem> getChildItemList(String category) {
    ArrayList childItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection(category).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    ChildItem childItem = new ChildItem();
                    childItem.setTrackTitle(document.getString("title"));
                    childItem.setAuthor(document.getString("author"));
                    childItem.setDuration(document.getString("duration"));
                    childItem.setImage(document.getString("image"));
                    childItemList.add(childItem);

                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(BrowseTracksActivity.this, task.getException() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    });
    if (childItemList.size() ==0) getChildItemList(category); // когда я добавляю эту строку, то у меня выходит ошибка (ниже)

    return childItemList;
}
```

вставляю данные в recycler View:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChildViewHolder childViewHolder, int position) {

        ChildItem childItem = ChildItemList.get(childViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        childViewHolder.trackTitle.setText(childItem.getTrackTitle());
        childViewHolder.author.setText(childItem.getAuthor());
        childViewHolder.duration.setText(childItem.getDuration());

        Glide.with(childViewHolder.itemView.getContext()).load("gs://clearmind1-c3475.appspot.com/Дизайн без названия.png")
                .into(childViewHolder.photo);
    }
```

logcat (он просто вызывает этот же самый, пока не закроет приложение):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8188KB
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.getState(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:573)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:154)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1291)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:466)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.offer(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.add(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1077)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.add(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:849)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:336)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:562)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:654)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.execute(AsyncQueue.java:299)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.executeAndReportResult(AsyncQueue.java:324)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.access$500(AsyncQueue.java:205)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.enqueue(AsyncQueue.java:428)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.enqueue(AsyncQueue.java:439)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.enqueueAndForget(AsyncQueue.java:477)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.listen(FirestoreClient.java:177)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.addSnapshotListenerInternal(Query.java:1145)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.getViaSnapshotListener(Query.java:970)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:956)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:931)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:109)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
        at com.example.clearmind1.BrowseTracksActivity.getChildItemList(BrowseTracksActivity.java:129)
```

Comment: А где у вас обновление адаптера? Или когда "не загружаются" колбек идёт в `else`?

Comment: Я сначала получаю все данные  и только потом отправляю создаю адаптер.  parentItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); сразу же после создания адаптера ничего не изменит, темболее, пытаюсь получить все данные в  цикле for each, поэтому больше не возвращать к этому коду

Comment: Метод onComplete слушателя загрузки срабатывает асинхронно. Те получается что, ты добавляешь слушатель базе, в него еще ни чего не пришло, но уже выполняется эта строчка кода - "if (childItemList.size() ==0) getChildItemList(category)" которая рекурсивно вызывает еще раз этот метод, еще добавляется слушатель на базу, в который, естественно, тоже сразу не приходит результат, и так пока не вылетет с StackOverflowError! Надо переделать метод getChildItemList, а еще лучше избавится от него вовсе. При старте экрана запускай лоадер, и жди пока отработает onComplete, и из него уже создавай адаптер

Comment: я убрала условие которое вы сказали убрать, и добавила  parentItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); а остальное вроде все так и есть. 
Я вызываю onComplete, и только потом создаю адаптер

Comment: Хорошо, а фото тогда почему не загружаются?

Comment: Ссылка, которую ты отдаешь в Glide не для обращения к хранилища снаружи, это внутренний идентификатор (на сколько мне помнится раньше в Fairbase Storage была возможность получить абсолютную ссылку, сейчас уже нет). Загружай картинки как в доке сказано, там несколько способов, каким нибудь получится - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: Можете показать листинг решения этого вопроса

Comment: @AndreyKokorin, задайте свой вопрос со своим кодом. Не факт что ваша ситуация аналогична и у автора вопроса этот код сохранился. И не факт что участники дискуссии присутствуют на сайте.